# how to remove last comma from the string using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I am storing multiple selected option value to the textbox and concatenate with comma but dont want to add in last of the string. hear is my code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<select id="garden" name="garden" multiple="multiple">
  <option value="1">Flowers</option>
  <option value="2">Shrubs</option>
  <option value="3">Trees</option>
  <option value="4">Bushes</option>
  <option value="5">Grass</option>
  <option value="6">Dirt</option>
</select>
<input type="text" name="store" id="store" />
<script>
$("#garden").change(function () {
  var str = "";
  $("select option:selected").each(function () {
        str += $(this).val() + ",";
      });
    $('#store').val(str).attr('rows',str.length) ;
})
.trigger('change');
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could do this using .substring():

```
 $('#store').val(str.substring(0,str.length-1)).attr('rows',str.length-1) ;
```

Answer (score 6):

simply use,

in palce of this

```
         $('#store').val(str).attr('rows',str.length) ;
```

use

```
         str=str.slice(0,-1);
```

This is enough to omit the last comma.

Answer (score 1):

Use `.substring` on your completed string

```
var str = "";
$("select option:selected").each(function () {
    str += $(this).val() + ",";
});
str = str.substring(0, str.length - 1); // remove the last char in your case the ,
$('#store').val(str).attr('rows',str.length) ;
```

Answer (score 0):

try this code...

```
$('#store').val(str.substring(0,str.lastIndexOf(','))).attr('rows',str.length-1) ;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#store').val(str.substr(0,str.length-1)).attr('rows',str.length-1) ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `.slice(start, end)` this way:

```
$('#store').val(str.slice(0,-1)).attr('rows',str.length);
```

`end` in slice `'-'` will subtract from last item in the string.